# Не запускается Selenium через PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Уже все облазил, но не могу понять в чём причина, видимо чего-то не замечаю.
Код не работает только в PyCharm, а в VS Code всё прекрасно работает.
Нужна помощь, хотя бы подсказать куда смотреть.... Код и ошибку прикрепляю ниже.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file('1.png')
    driver.get(url='https://stackoverflow.com/')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.save_screenshot('2.png')
    time.sleep(2)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vadim/PycharmProjects/python_selenium/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
  File "/home/vadim/PycharmProjects/python_selenium/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/vadim/PycharmProjects/python_selenium/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/vadim/PycharmProjects/python_selenium/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 272, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/vadim/PycharmProjects/python_selenium/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 364, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/vadim/PycharmProjects/python_selenium/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/vadim/PycharmProjects/python_selenium/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x557f6ee53463 <unknown>
#1 0x557f6ec178d8 <unknown>
#2 0x557f6ec3fb6a <unknown>
#3 0x557f6ec3ac05 <unknown>
#4 0x557f6ec7e802 <unknown>
#5 0x557f6ec7e2af <unknown>
#6 0x557f6ec76443 <unknown>
#7 0x557f6ec473c5 <unknown>
#8 0x557f6ec48531 <unknown>
#9 0x557f6eea5dce <unknown>
#10 0x557f6eea9192 <unknown>
#11 0x557f6ee8a93e <unknown>
#12 0x557f6eeaa103 <unknown>
#13 0x557f6ee7dd85 <unknown>
#14 0x557f6eecb0a8 <unknown>
#15 0x557f6eecb239 <unknown>
#16 0x557f6eee6492 <unknown>
#17 0x7ff00540f1da <unknown>
#18 0x7ff005497d84 clone
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг у кого-то возникнет такая же ошибка или PyCharm не будет видеть интерпретатор, то это проблема самого PyCharma, у меня он был скачан из Менеджера приложений.
Лучше удалить его и скачать нормальный через офф.сайт, тогда всё заработает.